# Displaying Searched Terms On Results Page Issue

Tags: php, preg-replace

On my search results page I would like to display what the user has searched for. I know I can use the following to display the actual value that was input.

```
<?php echo $_POST['category_name']; ?>
```

Here's an example of the search form

```
<option value="18120" class="cat-audio">Audio</option>
```

So, my results page reads as follows "Displaying results in 18120 category".
And I would like for it to display "Displaying results in Audio category".

I know there's a way to do this, but I don't quite know the verbiage to do a proper google search. Any help is greatly appreciated, should be a pretty easy solution for you intermediate/advanced php'ers!

Answer (score 0):

You can not get text of option by PHP like that, it needs to be passed through value or as a parameter depending on the way you are calling PHP script. Try this:

```
<option value="18120-Audio" class="cat-audio">Audio</option>
```

In your PHP:

```
<?php 
   $catIDName = isset($_POST['category_name']) ? $_POST['category_name'] : ''; 
   $split     = explode("-", $catIDName);

   if (count($split) == 2) {
      $catID   = array_shift($split);
      $catName = array_shift($split);

      echo 'Displaying results in ' . $catID . ' ' . $catName; //Audio
   }
?>
```